# dynamic shovels fail in Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I am trying to create dynamic shovels in my RabbitMQ instance both via code and using the UI. In both the cases, I am able to create the shovel. However , it's failing later on and is not able to move messages as desired.

Via Postman

```
PUT -- http://rabbitinstance011:15672/api/parameters/shovel/dev_test/test01

{"value": {"src-protocol": "amqp091", "src-uri": "amqp://naxi@example.com@/dev_test",
 "src-queue": "dlq1", "dest-protocol": "amqp091", 
 "dest-uri": "amqp://naxi@example.com@/dev_test",
  "dest-queue": "q1", "src-delete-after": "queue-length"}}
```

Response : `201`

On the UI -> admin -> Shovel Status

```
{failed_to_connect_using_provided_uris,
    [{rabbit_amqp091_shovel,make_conn_and_chan,2,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_amqp091_shovel.erl"},{line,324}]},
     {rabbit_amqp091_shovel,connect_source,1,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_amqp091_shovel.erl"},{line,78}]},
     {rabbit_shovel_worker,handle_cast,2,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_shovel_worker.erl"},{line,64}]},
     {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1050}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
```

I receive the same errors when I try to do all of this using code as well as from the UI instead of postman.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple. Had to create a new user without '@' in the username.